# Scala variable scope in object

Tags: scala

I'm looking at http://hseeberger.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/introduction-to-category-theory-in-scala/ and there's a bit of code that I can't understand how it works:

```
object Functor {

  def fmap[A, B, F[_]](as: F[A])(f: A => B)(implicit functor: Functor[F]): F[B] =
    functor.fmap(as)(f)

  implicit object ListFunctor extends Functor[List] {
    def fmap[A, B](f: A => B): List[A] => List[B] =
      as => as map f
  }
}
```

Specifically, how is `ListFunctor.fmap` accessing `as` when the definition of `as` is in the scope of `Functor.fmap` and (as far as I can tell) inaccessible to  `ListFunctor.fmap`?

(related with a twist) There's a previous iteration to the above code that's defined:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] extends GenericFunctor[Function, Function, F] {
  final def fmap[A, B](as: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] =
    fmap(f)(as)
}

object ListFunctor extends Functor[List] {
  def fmap[A, B](f: A => B): List[A] => List[B] = as => as map f
}
```

But again, `as` seems to be magically accessible to `ListFunctor`. I guess if I understand one of these, I'll understand the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the same `as`, just the same name is (probably not quite) accidentally used in two places. The `as => as map f` is a function definition, and the `as` before the arrow is a declaration of a parameter for this very function.

It would be completely equivalent if written as `x => x map f`.